# How many integers from $1$ through $999,999$ contains digit $1$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many integers from $1$ through $999,999$ contains digit $1$?

I have no idea to solve this problem. Have anyone give me some advice?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How many numbers between 1 through 999999 do NOT contain the digit $1$?  It may help to explicitly write out the initial zeros for numbers less than $100000$ so that all your numbers have six digits.

Comment: Number of integers with no digit $=1$ is $9^6-1$

Comment: Divide up the problem..count the number of 1 digit numbers that do not contain a "1". Thats easy, obviously, then do it for 2 digit numbers. Do you see a pattern in the logic of that calculation? Now expand that to 3 digits, 4, 5 etc etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How many numbers don't contain a 1?

First lets extend our range: $0 = 000000$ to $999999$

From this We can work out the probability that the number does not contain a 1

$$\left(\frac{9}{10} \right)^{6}$$

And the total number

$$10^6 \times \left(\frac{9}{10} \right)^{6} = 531441$$

Now we have over counted by 1 because we extended the range so there are $531440$ numbers that don't contain any 1 so there must be $999999 - 531440 = 468559$ that do contain at least one 1.

Comment: VERY nice,simple solution!

Comment: I got it! You are a man. Thanks so much!!

Comment: $10^6\times\left(\frac9{10}\right)^6=9^6$ which is exactly what Asaf's hint gives.

Comment: True.  I did it this way because I thought it was more clear where it came from.

Answer (score 8):

**HINT:** Consider those integers as six character strings over the alphabet $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. How many strings *don't* contain $1$? It might be helpful to add $0$ to your range of integers first.

Comment: Another way of phrasing it: how many 6-digit numbers can you write with the set $\{0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ (note there's no $1$). Since $0$ is included in the list, then you are accounting for every possible number between $0$ and $999,999$

Comment: for six character strings, there are 8*9^5? Because the first digit cannot be zero. Am I right?

Comment: @mathR: No, consider $1$ as $000001$.

Comment: still have no idea...

Answer (score 2):

While Asaf's answer is the simplest, we can also use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to answer this question.

Let $A_i$ be the set of numbers with a '$1$' in digit $i$. The sum of the intersection of $k$ of the $A_i$'s is
$$
10^{6-k}\binom{6}{k}
$$
That is for each of the $\binom{6}{k}$ choices of the $A_i$'s, there are $10^6-k$ numbers with a '$1$' in the specified digit. The Inclusion-Exclusion Principle says that the count of numbers containing a $1$ is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^6(-1)^{k-1}10^{6-k}\binom{6}{k}
$$
which is
$$
\begin{align}
&10^5\binom{6}{1}-10^4\binom{6}{2}+10^3\binom{6}{3}-10^2\binom{6}{4}+10^1\binom{6}{5}-10^0\binom{6}{6}\\
&=600000-150000+20000-1500+60-1\\[8pt]
&=468559
\end{align}
$$